# Nested getJSON calls using dynamic url from previous getJSON calls results

Tags: jquery, json, nested, getjson

i hope someone can help me find a more reliable way of doing this.

We have 3 urls and that can't be changed.
First getJSON call takes url1 to get all the sections, inside its callback function we have a loop and on each iteration we make a second getJSON call using url2 + section name to get all the articles ids, then the callback function for this second call uses each id to make a third getJSON call using url3 + id to get all the details of each article. There's more code not shown here, but the main problem comes from this block.

```
$.getJSON(url1, function(sections) {

for(var i=0; i < sections.length; i++) {

    $.getJSON(url2 + sections.contents[i].name, function(ids) {

        $.getJSON(url3 + ids.contents[0].id, function(article) {
            // ==== Code to create article's body using only the first result ====
        })

        for(var j=0; j < ids.length; j++) {
            // ==== Code to create a list of links to all the articles ====
        }

    })

}})
```

I know there has to be a much better way to do this but I still don't know how.
The stucture of the info inside the jsons can't be changed, so these calls have to be made based on the results of the previous one, but i want to avoid making calls inside a loop.
**Problem**: As it is to be expected, since the 2nd json call is inside a loop, sometimes the results of the first iteration haven't arrived, but the results of the 2nd iteration have (when i=1 in this case).

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: I'm not really clear on what the problem is, but I can see one stumbling point.  Are you using the i variable inside the 3rd JSON callback? That'll cause trouble.

Comment: The problem is with the calls being made on each iteration of the loop, and sice the loop is not going to wait until the first call is made and has completed to make the next one, sometimes the result of the second json call on the 2nd iteration completes first, which means that the first section i can start working with to generate content, is the 2nd on the json. And nope, not using that i inside the 3rd call.

Answer (score 0):

You could `getJSON(url).done(function(json) {})` which ensures that inside the .done block the call has completed and the results are available.